# Why do chi-squared and F statistic formulas involve $s^2$ not $s^2/n$?

Tags: variance, chi-squared-test, standard-error, f-test

Could someone please clarify why in Chi-squared and F-statistic calculation formulas sample variances are used as $s^2$ and not $s^2/n$ (like in Z or t tests)?

$\chi^2 = \frac{(n-1)s^2}{\sigma^2} $

$F = \frac{s^2_1}{s^2_2}$

Comment: Which formulas specifically are you asking about?  Statistics with these distributions appear in many contexts and have many different formulas.

Comment: I edited the post, it should be clearer now.